# Implications as functions in type theory

Tags: type-theory

Unpacking $P\Rightarrow Q$ in logic as $P\to Q$ in type theory I'm reaching confusion.  (Ref. [Homotopy Type Theory](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) p. 55, 154).  Suppose what I want in logic is something like this $(\forall x)(P(x)\implies Q(x))$.  I think then of $P,Q:X\to Boolean$, but that makes $P$ and $Q$ inhabitants of the type $X\to Boolean$ not types themselves.  So what could $P\to Q$ mean?

To make it very precise suppose I want to define an equivalence relation on terms of type A.  I want a term $\sim:A\to A\to 2$.  Then I want to enforce the symmetric condition: $x\sim y\implies y\sim x$.  So does this become $$\sum_{A:\mathcal{U}}\sum_{\sim:A\to A\to 2}\prod_{x,y:A} x\sim y\to y\sim x$$
While syntatically translatable, again, how could $x\sim y\to y\sim x$ since $x\sim y$ is a number, not a type?

Happy to be told I overlooked the answer in some place I've not yet considered.

Comment: For what it's worth, $2$ is a type: it's the type with two elements.

Comment: yeah, one could perhaps make the view "everything is a type", including true/false, 0,1 etc., But what would a function true->true mean that true->false couldn't also mean?  In particular how does that view support the concept of implication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Homotopy Type Theory and other constructive type theories derived from Martin-Löf type theory, the idea is propositions as *types*. Instead of a proposition $P$ being a Boolean that is either "true" or "false", a proposition is a type. So it's not $P:\mathbf 2$, it's $P:\mathcal U$. Now the equivalent of $P$ being "true" is $P$ being inhabited meaning there is a value $t$ of type $P$. $P\to Q:\mathcal U$ when $P,Q:\mathcal U$. A binary predicate would be represented by a value $\sim: A\to A \to \mathcal U$ thus $x\sim y$ is not a number, it is a type. The proposition that $\sim$ is symmetric is represented by the type $(\prod_{x:A}\prod_{y:A}x\sim y \to y\sim x):\mathcal U$. $\sim$ will be symmetric if there is a value (inhabitant) of that type, i.e. there is some $p:\prod_{x:A}\prod_{y:A}x\sim y \to y\sim x$.

Comment: So it is permitted to have a function into $\mathcal{U}$?  I confess it feels correct but at odds with constructing equality.  Imagine a typed programming languages with `def ==(x:A,y:A):Any = ...` (or in Java `public Class equals(A x, A y) {…}` instead of returning `Boolean`). It changes semantics from binary outcomes to possibly infinite.  While one might interpret $x\sim y$ as inhabited vs. uninhabited to recover the binary "true/false", the actual inhabitant of $x\sim y$ could be much more information, if I'm understanding this approach.

Comment: @AlgeboyAlge if I may add something, in the idea of the paradigm _proposition as types_ a proposition is _the type of its proofs_ (hence the interpretation of truth as inhabitation as described by Derek Elkins' answer).

Comment: So it isn't just any type, but a type for the proof of equality.  I.e. you cannot just give an oracle type answer of $x\sim y$, you have to return a proof as to why $x\sim y$?  So if one where to think in code it might suggest a type `Proposition` and so `def ==(x:A, y:A):Proposition` would replace the ubiquitous `def ==(x:A,y:A):Boolean`.   The effect being you can verify the proof of equality.

Comment: @Algeboy This is *constructive* type theory. Constructivists don't just care whether some proposition is "true", they care *how* it is "true". Constructive logic is not classical; something can be neither "true" nor "false" or, more accurately, it can turn out that neither $P$ nor $\neg P$ (defined as $P\to\bot$ where $\bot$ is the empty type) are inhabited. You can't test for inhabitation, but there's no need for it. The *program* is the proof. If you have a program of type $\prod_{x:A}\prod_{y:A}x\sim y\to y\sim x$ that type checks, then the statement is proven. There's no need to run it.